# Staff label is not shown beside the staff username in 'Recent Badges'

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-team, user-labels, recent-badges

This is how the 'Recent Badges' section looks like in MSE home page: (you have to hide hot network questions in the profile settings in order to see it)

[image]

When I saw a particular user, whom I did not know, with a Mod label, I was shocked thinking that a new moderator has been appointed. When I went to their profile, I realised that they were staff.

Please include the staff label for staff in 'Recent Badges' section.

Comment: Its MSE though, its unlikely you'll see an unfamiliar face as a moderator.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek haha... we never know...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek actually... I'm pretty sure most new users, who don't have SO account, have no idea who ChrisF is, he's not very active (publicly at least) here on MSE.

Comment: Anyway, as for the bug, this "recent badges" widget is ancient, and was never maintained very well. No wonder it's not in their "places to update when making changes" list. I'm also afraid that if and when they try to fix this bug, they'll just drop this widget as the fix would be too complex and they'll want "cleaner" design.